# unable to change webview height programmatically

Tags: java, android

I set a webview on my main layout and I am unable to resize it programmatically. Webview is in the "main" layout.
If do the same with his contentainer "layoutA", works but not a solution, I need to set only webview view. Thank you.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            final RelativeLayout LayoutA = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.aLayout);
            webviewA = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewA);           

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                     LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) webviewA.getLayoutParams();

                      params.height -= 150;

                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

logcat,

```
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at com.xxxx.projecte1.webPush$1.run(webPush.java:109)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
07-06 11:23:21.204: E/AndroidRuntime(13795):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in imported package plz check packege for your case it should be if it not present than add it instead of other pkg like import android.widget.RelativeLayout etc...

```
 import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call invalidate() on your WebView.
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html ( Drawing Section )

Greets Flo

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams in your activity class.

Try to do it with

```
public void run() 
{
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) webviewA.getLayoutParams();
     params.height -= 150;    
}
```